# Terraform : I want to add DNS to my Autoscale Instances

Tags: terraform

Whats the Terraform API to add a route53 record to every instance provisioned by Auto-scaling ?

I also need to destroy the A record once instance is terminated.

My code deployment scripts make use of DNS name.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll find people are going to be more willing/able to assist if you provide some of the snippets of code you're working on, and an overview of what you've tried/what's not working.

Answer (score 2):

When autoscaling is in use, Terraform controls the overall autoscaling process but does not manage the *instances* produced by the auto-scaling system. Any actions that need to be taken as a result of instances being created and destroyed must therefore be triggered by auto-scaling itself, rather than by Terraform.

The [Auto Scaling Lifecycle Hooks](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/lifecycle-hooks.html) provide a way to trigger actions in response to changes in the statuses of instances in an autoscaling group.

In principle one could use auto-scaling lifecycle hooks to trigger running Terraform, but automatic, unattended Terraform runs are not a common usage and so there are currently no built-in mechanisms to make this work. A wrapper script of some kind would need to be written to orchestrate Terraform and deal with any errors that occur when running it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Martin.

Used Lambda and boto3 with Events in Cloudwatch to get around with this one. 
Passed a Tag 'cname' while starting instances via ASG.

- Insert and Upsert was fine.
- Delete was bit tricky as the Terminating Instance does not retain IP.

To delete, queried Route53 table using the CNAME while creating instances. 
And then ran a delete using boto3 on Route53 with IP as the 'Value'

Thanks.